# sh-zsh not catching any errors

Tags: flycheck, zsh

emacs 29.1
flycheck 32

test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
echo "test"
ech boo
```

`C-c ! v` gives

```
Syntax checkers for buffer test.sh in sh-mode:

First checker to run:

  sh-zsh
    - may enable:    yes
    - predicate:     t
    - executable:    Found at /usr/bin/zsh
    - next checkers: sh-shellcheck
```

but nothing shows up with syntax checking

nor does `C-c ! C-c` flycheck compile produce anything:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/" -*-
Compilation started at Tue Aug  8 16:19:45

/usr/bin/zsh --no-exec --no-globalrcs --no-rcs /home/pradmin/test.sh

Compilation finished at Tue Aug  8 16:19:45
```

yet running the program through emacs `C-c C-x` gives:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/" -*-
Comint started at Tue Aug  8 16:22:59

/home/pradmin/test.sh
test
/home/pradmin/test.sh:5: command not found: ech

Comint exited abnormally with code 127 at Tue Aug  8 16:22:59
```

**how to get flycheck to work using sh-zsh?**
(it works fine with clojure btw)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a syntax error.  You're trying to run a program named `ech` (which is a perfectly valid thing to do), and the code linter can't possibly know whether or not `ech` will be installed on whichever machine(s) this script may ultimately be running on, so it's not going to even *try* to validate that.

Comment: thx! i should have realized this from run output where it says: /home/pradmin/test.sh:5: **command not found: ech**